# Posting an image on google+ using interactive post

Tags: javascript, google-plus

Is there any way to add an image to a interactive post on google+?

https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive

It looks like it pulls the image from the `contenturl` parameter. But I don't seem to be able to control this image in any way. Maybe there is some sort of open-graph like markup that we can put on this page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title, description, and image data for the interactive post share is based on the contenturl parameter, as you noted. In particular, it uses snippet information from that page, as documented at https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/

You can use open-graph markup, and it should work correctly, although there have been issues with this recently. As the snippet documentation notes, better would be to use the schema.org microdata.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's unfortunate that you can't post a particular image but oh well.

Comment: You should be able to use open-graph or snippet markup to post a particular image.